# How to repair or work around a damaged usb port on the Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

While unplugging the usb cable from the Arduino, the plastic piece in the center of the port (the part that separates the pins) broke off and lodged into the end of the usb cable. I didn't notice that it broke off and when I plugged the cable back into the Arduino it bent one of the pins back onto itself.

[image]

How would you go about repairing this?

If I fail to repair it is there an alternate method to programming the board?

Comment: I was able to use a paperclip to carefully bend it back and put the plastic divider back in. I will just have to leave the cable plugged in from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to replace the whole socket in order to repair it. For that you would need:

- Soldering iron
- Solder sucker
- Solder wick
- Patience and experience

Or you just connect an FT232 breakout board to TX, RX and RESET as if you were making a breadboard arduino and program the board through that.

Comment: Also connect Vcc and GND of course.

Comment: That would (I hope) go without saying, although if the Arduino is separately powered the power connection is not needed, only ground.

Answer (score 1):

You could try bending the pin back, removing the white part from your cable, and gluing it back in.

Second option is to replace the USB socket on the Arduino board. You might be able to salvage a socket from some old electronics you still have lying around.

Third option is to cut one end of a spare USB cable, and solder the 4 wires inside the cable directly to the corresponding pads on the bottom of the broken socket. Add some glue to provide some strain-relieve to the cable.

Fourth option is an external USB to serial converter, like @Majenko suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to actually remove the whole thing and resolder it. There are many tutorials out there is you're new to soldering. This way, it is less probable that it creates a short or data loss during compilation.

If you don't want to solder, then you might be able to use an FTDI connector. FT232s are quite cheap.

Tx > Rx

Rx > Tx

Reset > Reset

Vcc > Vcc

GND > GND